# Transparent element in an opaque element

Tags: html, css, transparent

I want to set a white background on the main content but leave another element, nested inside, transparent.

The layout is something like this.

```
<div id="content">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, etc...</p>

  <div id="morecontent">
    <p>stuff</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

I'd want a white background on `#content`, but I don't want that background applied to `#morecontent`. In other words `#morecontent` would have the same background as the body.

Answer (score 1):

you will have to apply styles to the child to override the styles on the parent div. There is no other way to stop inheriting properties of parent. Apply background to "morecontent" div ..

Thank you